# Azure vnet peering with remote gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to access resources in a peered network via a remote gateway and not having much luck;

Network 1 - Has the gateway (p2s VPN)
Network 2 - Has target resource (VM1)

If I connect to the GW in NW1 from my laptop, I can't access resources in NW2. I've allowed traffic to be forwarded and configured allowing remote gateways

If I add an intermediate VM (VM2) in network 1, I can connect over the P2S to VM2 and then from VM2 to VM1.... i,e everything is open and accepting connections, just doesn't work straight through. I've opened up NSG with any any on the port as a test and still no luck

Anyone got this working?

Comment: needed a local route... doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a local route for the remote subnet

Comment: For the network novices amongst us, adding a local route is best done how?
When I look at `route print`, the VPN reports no gateway and all routes are "on-link", so how does someone find the IP address of the VPN gateway (and I'm guessing that's the private/internal IP address) to add a route for... I'm surprised when connecting the VPN doesn't add necessary routes from NW2 when you connect, but that's a different question.